# want thread to not die when parent exits - linux

Tags: c++, c, boost-thread

I do not want to use fork() because that adds a layer of IPC management I wish to avoid.  I would like to use a pthread.  I have seen an strace for clone, and I don't want to start managing the thread at the clone() level of detail.

To give them names:  A=main thread, B=worker thread.

I want B to be able to get a signal from A when A is going away.  A can register an atexit() for that.

A may go away either from an abort() or maybe even a SIGSEGV or other terminal signal.  B's job is all about logging:  A and B share a container with log msgs being created by A.  If A dies, I want B to  finish logging and THEN exit.

Right now if A exits, B exits, and I lose anything left in the log queue.

So my question is this:  is there a way to make B a bit more resilient so it sticks around and doesn't die with A?

Comment: pthread_join is what you're looking for if i understood correctly. parent should execute pthread_join(CHILD_PID)

Comment: @galchen: how would a `pthread_join()` call allow you to wait on a child *process*?

Comment: "The pthread_join() function suspends execution of the calling thread until the target thread terminates, unless the target thread has already terminated."

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be confusing *threads* and *processes*; the way you describe it, A is a process, not a thread. When `abort()` is called, or a `SIGSEGV` is encountered, and A exits, B -- which is a thread contained inside the process A -- disappears as well. There's no way around that, as B is inextricably linked to A. If you want a process to outlive A, then you must use `fork` and create a new process.

Now, you can absolutely have multiple threads in a process, and thread B could outlive thread A-prime which created it -- but both are subordinate to the process that contains them, and cannot outlive it.

Comment: Thanks for refreshing my memory.  It sounds as if the solution would be to make my "A" process a thread, A-prime.  THen we have the process, A, which joins the B and A-prime thread, and nothing more.  If A-prime SIGSEGV's, a registered signal handler for A-prime could signal B;  B could finish logging, A-prime aborts like it should;  B-prime exits.  Process A has joined both threads, so it now, too, terminates.  That bubbles the handler over into the thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can install a handler for both `atexit` and the signals you expect (in A), that pushes a final "I'm done here" message into the logging queue, then joins with (waits for) B before exiting the entire process.

Comment: This will however not work for SIGKILL, as this cannot be caught by the process

Comment: @king_nak: That's right. But with a two-process solution, a SIGKILL sent to the logger would much have the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

I think you wish to create the thread as detached using a pthread_attribute.

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

shows you how - just search down for "detached" :)  It will survive after the parent and you can do what you want with it afterward.